# Replace a table value for a key in lua

Tags: replace, lua, indexing, lua-table

I need to do replace a value for a key in lua, for example consider a table

```
t = {"book", "ball", "bank"}
```

here I need to change the value for "box" instead of "ball". how to do that ?

previously I tried as finding the value a key and change, but it didn't work!!!

```
for key, value in pairs(t) do
  if key == 2 then
    value = "box"
  end
end
```

but it didn't work.. if anyone knows alternative way please give me suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's logical.

In a loop the looping variables `key` and `value` are locals. So reassigning them, it just changes the value referenced by the local variable. After 1 run of the loop, locals run out of scope and are discarded.

To change the value in the table reference to the table itself like

```
 t[key]="box"
```

In this simple example just doing `t[2]="box"` would obviously also serve ;) (instead of having to loop through the whole table just to replace one value)
More in depth information can be found in the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.5).